# Is there an add-on or setting that will automatically redact email addresses in Outlook, when forwarding?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

When forwarding an email message in Windows Outlook 365, and you wish to keep private the senders and/or multiple previous senders.

Is there something that will redact the email addresses for us?  Or do I have to go in and redact them myself?

Comment: This *might* be acceptable at [softwarerecs.se] but you should also take a look at their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: A quick search here: Shows many similar questions https://superuser.com/search?q=outlook+365 -- "Software Recommendations" is a much smaller community.  And will likely not get looked at.  The communities are getting smaller and smaller as they get sliced.